# C++ data member

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have 2 objects, the only difference is a table. I want to create a class `Cfoo`, then

```
Cfoo A;
Cfoo B;
```

and let `A` and `B` have a different table.

the only way I know is pass table to `Cfoo` constructor. is there a better way?

Comment: Your description does not clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish. It is hard to help without a clear understanding of your objective.

Comment: Please define "table".

Comment: What is **table** here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad

#### Option 1

Passing only the `iterators` and handling `begin` and `end` to your constructor and `copy` the table to the `class Cfoo`

#### Option 2

Have the table as a member of `class Cfoo` and provide `accesors` to that `table` in the form of `iterators` and just use that member

#### Option 3 and depends on the use of table

Have the table as a public member of `class Cfoo`